# Is there a way to check the region of an S3Client through the AWS Java SDK v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am migrating / upgrading a project from Java SDK `v1` to Java SDK `v2`.

One of the functions needed for the project auto-detects the region and saves it.

And as an error checking measure after setting the region it calls [getRegionName()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getRegionName--) on the `AmazonS3Client`.

In v2 of the SDK, `AmazonS3Client` is replaced with `S3Client`. As far as I can tell, there is no `getRegionName`. Any ideas what I could use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In S3Client Java SDK v2 there is `getBucketLocation` function that returns the region bucket resides in.

You can also find more info in the official [docs](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html).